# In the sequence $1,3,7,15,31\ldots$ each term is $2\cdot\text{immediately preceding term}+1$. What is the $n$-th term?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I readily see that it is $2^n-1$, but how can I deduce the $n$-th term from the given pattern i.e. $n$-th term $= 2\cdot(n-1)\text{th term} + 1$ without computation.

Comment: Compute $a_n-a_{n-1}$

Comment: You question should read immediately preceding term since for example, 3 is a term that precedes (comes before in order) 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an explicit proof by induction. Given that $a_{n+1}=2a_n+1$ for $n=0,1,...$, with $a_0=1$ prove the proposition $\mathcal P(n):\;\,a_n=2^n-1$ for $n=0,1,...$ .

We are given that $\mathcal P(n)$ holds for $n=0$. Suppose now that we know $\mathcal P(n)$ for $n=k$; that is, $\mathcal P(k):\;\,a_k=2^k-1$. Now $a_{k+1}=2a_k+1=2(2^k-1)+1=2^{k+1}-1$. We have shown that $\mathcal P(k)\Rightarrow\mathcal P(k+1)$. Hence, by induction, $\mathcal P(n)$ holds for all $n=0,1,...$ .

Comment: It is given that $a_{n+1}= 2(a_n) + 1 $.

Comment: Thanks, @AdityaChintalapati. I have got rid of the wrong parentheses now.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Compare to the sequence of powers of $2$.

Answer (score 2):

$$a_1=1 \hspace{1cm} a_{n+1}=2a_n+1$$

You can write the second equality as: $$a_{n+1}+1=2(a_n+1)$$

Therefore:$$a_n+1=(a_1+1)\cdot2^{n-1}=2^n$$

And finally: $$a_n=2^n-1$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on the equation after 'Therefore"?

Comment: Suppose we have a sequence $(U_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}*}$ which satisfies $U_{n+1}=a\cdot U_n$ where $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $U_n=U_1\cdot a^{n-1}$. This can be proven using recurrence.

$$U_1=U_1\cdot a^0$$

Suppose there exists $n\geq 1$ such that: $$U_n=U_1\cdot a^{n-1}$$

Then $$U_{n+1}=aU_n=a\cdot U_1\cdot a^{n-1}= U_1\cdot a^{n+1-1}$$

Then for all $n\geq 1: U_n=U_1\cdot a^{n-1}$   
  
This equation can also be adjusted if you have a different starting point.  
For example, if your sequence starts at $0$, that relation can also be written as: $$U_n=U_0\cdot a^n$$

Comment: I am not entirely familiar with the notation of higher mathematics. What does $U_n$ stand for?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I deduced the formula from your title before I saw the formula in your post.

Your recursive relation multiplies the previous term by two. What other sequence do I know that does that? Ah, yes, $2^n$ also does that. I will compare the given sequence with my sequence. Oh, they differ by one. OK, the formula must be

$$a_n=2^n-1$$

If that had not worked, I would next have tried the method of finite differences. Take the difference between successive terms, and perhaps look at the differences of those differences. That often leads to a formula for the sequence. (This is what @Claude Leibovici suggested in his comment.)

Answer (score 1):

The recursion relation is $a_{n+1}=2a_n+1$, with $a_1=1$. Consider $b_n=a_n+1$; then
$$
b_{n+1}=a_{n+1}+1=2a_n+1+1=2(a_n+1)=2b_n
$$
and $b_1=2$. Then $b_n=2^n$ by the recursive definition of powers and so $a_n=b_n-1=2^n-1$.

Comment: Your proof is intuitive. Could you describe shortly the recursive definition of powers? I grasped the essence of it reading your answer but would like an explicit definition.

Comment: @AdityaChintalapati $c^1=c$, $c^{n+1}=c^n\cdot c$. So in our case $b_1=2$, $b_{n+1}=b_n\cdot 2$ and it's the same as before with $c=2$.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I ended up having to solve the same question the other day, and initially looked here first.

Firstly we see the recursive formula $x_{n+1} = 2x_{n} + 1$. Letting our first term be $x_1$, then 
$$x_2 = 2x_1 + 1,$$
$$x_3 = 2x_2 + 1,$$
$$x_4 = 2x_3 + 1.$$
Rewriting these in terms of $x_1$ and looking at the powers of two yields:
$$x_2 = 2x_1 + 1 = 2^1x_1 + 1$$
$$x_3 = 4x_1 + 3 = 2^2x_1 + 3$$
$$x_4 = 8x_1 + 7 = 2^3x_1 + 7$$
It can be seen that $x_n = 2^{n-1}x_1 + x_{n-1}$. We already know that  $x_{n} = 2x_{n-1} + 1$. This can rearranged to show $x_{n-1} = \frac{x_{n}-1}{2}$
therefore:
$$x_n = 2^{n-1}x_1 + x_{n-1}$$
$$x_n = 2^{n-1}x_1 + \frac{x_n-1}{2}$$
$$2x_n = 2*2^{n-1}x_1 + x_n-1$$
$$x_n = 2^nx_1-1$$ And in our case $x_1 = 1$ therefore $$x_n = 2^n-1$$